# TP Link TL-SG1016D Login

Tags: networking

I purchased a TP Link Gigabit Switch TL-SG1016D.

Can I login into this switch and if so how do I do so?

Best Regards,
Kevin Downey

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have a login, as it is an unmanaged switch (i. e. you cannot log in).  It is a plug and play device - it only functions like a high end hub. Neither does it need any configuration.

You can check the [user manual](http://static.highspeedbackbone.net/pdf/TP-Link%20TL-SG1024D%20Gigabit%20Switch%20Manual.pdf).